# What is meant by unbalanced force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

If the forces on an object are equal and opposite, they are said to be
balanced, and the object experiences no change in motion. If they are not
equal and opposite, then the forces are unbalanced and the motion of the
object changes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: its come from Newton’s Laws of Motion?

Comment: @ImranNiaz Which one of Newton's laws of motion?

Comment: Law of Inertia. if we have value How can we give outpot

Comment: So you mean Newton's first law?

Comment: yes thas i wanna say the main  reason equation on BS Level works same or they change

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: i am looking for alot of answers from the same question .

Comment: for example how it work on real-time, why , where , when we need these laws

Comment: @ImranNiaz Your question is much too broad and will surely be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Like people have stated, your question is not too clear, but I'll try my best to answer anyway. You seem to be familiar with Newton's Laws of Motion, and hence I'll be using them to answer your question. Newton's First Law of Motion says that a body at rest will remain at rest, and a body in motion will remain in the same motion, unless acted upon by an external force. It is not tough to see what this exactly means. Bodies have no natural tendency to slow down or speed up. For a long time, it was thought that being at rest is a body's "natural" state, but that is completely wrong. Unless you have an external force acting on a body, the body will not change it's state of motion, whatever that may be. As soon as an external force is present, the body undergoes acceleration. Now, the net external force on a body is simply the vector sum of all the forces acting on it. Note that it isn't the traditional algebraic sum you're used to, but a special kind of sum called the vector sum. If the vector sum of all the forces acting on the body is 0, we say that the forces acting on the body are balanced, as they cancel each other out, in a sense. If it is anything but 0, then the forces are unbalanced, and the body is experiencing a non-zero net force and will undergo acceleration. If you're not sure as to what the vector sum actually is, just know for now that it's a kind of addition performed on quantities that are dependent on their magnitudes as well as directions. I hope this helps.